# Read files in django without saving

Tags: django, django-views

I use request.FILES in test django project, but dictionary always empty

I use django 1.11.17

```
#views.py
class UploadMenuView(CreateView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        file = request.FILES.popitem()
        print(file.name)
        return HttpResponse(file.name)

#templates/admin/change_list.html
...
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'dashboard:upload-menu' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}

        <input type="file" value="Select file" name="file"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload menu"/>
    </form>
...

#urls.py
url(r'upload-menu/', UploadMenuView.as_view(), name='upload-menu')
```

All my tryes end with Exception Value: 'popitem(): dictionary is empty'. But i see my file in F12 as POST request. key: file, value: file.txt

Comment: You need to specify `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form, otherwise `request.FILES` will be empty.

Comment: But what if I don't wanna use forms. Or I just need to add this key ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add to form in templates/admin/change_list.html

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

After that get text from file:

```
file = request.FILES['file'].read()
```